# Did the French ever use the decimal time in science?

Tags: units, time

Have you ever seen a scientific paper/document that uses the decimal time introduced during the French Revolution?

I'm not looking for any paper that uses decimal time like in astronomy, but instead I look for a scientific paper made during the French Revolution when the metric time was official. Possibly, I'm trying to find a paper where some physical phenomena is measured in the metric seconds/minutes/hours.

Comment: Have you a source showing that decimal/metric time was ever 'official' in revolutionary France? Yes it was proposed and a few decimal clocks made, but that's not the same thing.

Comment: I've seen scientific instruments (clocks and angle measuring tools) with decimal division. Sometimes (rarely) they can be found on e-bay. Since they were produced, I believe they were also used.

Comment: @terry-s  i may look it up but I think it was official according to Wikipedia article "Decimal Time". Now that I read it more carefully it was officially official for one year between 1794 and 1795

Comment: Why do you exclude astronomy, the area where the decimal division of the day is most useful? For example, the period of revolution of Mars is 686.979579 days or 1y 321d 23h 30′ 35″6. The decimal version is convenient in calculations where time is a multiplier or a divisor, like in the third law of Kepler. In ~1799, Laplace used the decimal division of the day in 'Traitè de mécanique céleste', and in 'The System of the World'.   Maybe he also used the pendulum formula, which contains the oscillation time as a multiplier, but that time is not measured in days.

Comment: Lavoisier had his head chopped off before he could publish anything, and Carnot was probably too busy.

Comment: @jkien do you have an astronomy paper from that time?

Comment: Not a paper, but a book by Laplace from 1796:  Exposition du système du monde [1](https://books.google.nl/books?id=HrMWAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA1&dq=%22Systeme+du+Monde%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjT0f_Juo7gAhVPJlAKHWCWCtgQ6AEIMjAB#v=onepage&q=979579&f=false); English  [2](https://books.google.nl/books?id=yW3nd4DSgYYC&pg=PA76&lpg=PA76&dq=laplace++686d,979579&source=bl&ots=FkJDezuSGv&sig=ACfU3U3mG5_5SmxhXtH8oZaHGbAhpXxi1A&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjDnsfet47gAhURblAKHbB2CQ8Q6AEwAHoECAcQAQ#v=onepage&q=laplace%20%20686d%2C979579&f=false)), stating that the period of the revolution of Mars is 686jours 979579.

Comment: and from 1799 a book on interest calculation, for example over 6,967 year at 5% per year. [3](https://books.google.nl/books?id=NWc7AAAAcAAJ&pg=PA35&dq=jours+decimal&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjD1c7B2I3gAhVRK1AKHfTXBl0Q6AEILDAA#v=onepage&q=%2218%20jours%22&f=false)